# check for duplicate email entry using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to check for duplicate emails in a form submit.

My php looks like this

```
$value = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['email'];
$value3 = $_POST['address'];
$value4 = $_POST['city'];
$value5 = $_POST['state'];
$value6 = $_POST['zip'];
$value7 = $_POST['primary'];
$value8 = $_POST['secondary'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO fusiodoseOne (`name`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `primary`, `secondary`) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7', '$value8')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}

//

function createUser($email){
   $sql = "SELECT count(email) FROM fusiodoseOne WHERE email='$value2'" ;

   $result = mysql_result(mysql_query($sql),0) ;

   if( $result > 0 ){
    die( "There is already a user with that email!" ) ;
   }//end if
```

What am i doing wrong. The duplicate email entries are still going through

The jquery looks like this

```
$.post("demo.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){    
        $('.successMessageHolder').show();
        $('.alertMsg').hide();
    });
```

Comment: You're passing `$email` into your createUser function, but then using `$value2` inside the query.

Comment: Before preventing duplicate e-mails, I'd learn how to protect from SQL Injection, also consider using mysqli or PDO instead of mysql functions.

Comment: Test the output of your query and see if it's correct [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Also consider using `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: If you used unique column for email, it'd be impossible to insert a nonunique value. Run this (or similar) sql-command: alter table fusiodoseOne add unique(email) [of course still it'd be good to check it beforehands]

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the createUser() function.

First: You pass $email as a param, but don't use it, i.e. you use $value2 instead which is in global scope and you can't access it unless you pass it as a parameter ($email in your case) or declare global in function body. It seems it should be:

```
function createUser($email){
   $sql = "SELECT count(email) FROM fusiodoseOne WHERE email='$email'" ;

   $result = mysql_result(mysql_query($sql),0) ;

   if( $result > 0 ){
    die( "There is already a user with that email!" ) ;
   }//end if
```

Second: At what point exactly is the function called? This is a definition, but where and how is it used?